# Weka features selection (InfoGainAttributeEval, ChiSquaredAttributeEval)

Tags: weka

I am new to Weka, I have 2-class data to classify. I could classify it using the weighting (word occurrences, TFIDF or word presence ). I wanted to improve the accuracy of the classifier using the feature selection mechanism integrated in Weka as follows:

```
                BufferedReader trainReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataSource)); 
               trainInsts = new Instances(trainReader); 
               trainInsts.setClassIndex(trainInsts.numAttributes() - 1); 


// I am using the filter to convert the data from string to numeric 

                  StringToWordVector STWfilter = new StringToWordVector(); 
                  FilteredClassifier model = new FilteredClassifier(); 
                  model.setFilter(STWfilter); 
                  STWfilter.setOutputWordCounts(true); 


int n = 400; // number of features to select 
      AttributeSelection attributeSelection = new  AttributeSelection(); 
     ranker = new Ranker(); 
     ranker.setNumToSelect(n); 

       infoGainAttributeEval = new InfoGainAttributeEval(); 
       attributeSelection.setEvaluator(infoGainAttributeEval); 
attributeSelection.setSearch(ranker); 

     attributeSelection.setInputFormat(trainInsts); 
     trainInsts = Filter.useFilter(trainInsts, attributeSelection); 

 Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainInsts); 

        eval.crossValidateModel(model, trainInsts, folds, new Random(1));
```

This works and I could see slight improvements against using the standard weighting methods such as (word occurrence). I am not sure if what I did is correct. Because I feel the feature selection method is same as the weighting methods. Also must I give the "n" number of feature I should have? this is influence the result of the classifier significantly, how this can be set, for example when I have 3000 instances, how many feature I should select? also is there any way in Weka to obtain the number of feature (word) I have in my data? for example with 2000 instances, the best accuracy was with n=400 .

Any comments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aswering your questions one by one:

1. "*Because I feel the feature selection method is same as the weighting methods.*" Well, they are much different. First, weighting is not supervised, it does not take into account the class information; while feature selection is supervised, and aims at selecting the most predictive features (words) according to a quality metric that measures the "coupling" between the feature and the class. Second, most feature selection metrics (like e.g. Information Gain) do not take into account weights, only occurences - they show the same results (scores) for TFxIDF or for binary features.
2. "*Also must I give the "n" number of feature I should have?*" In WEKA you can set up the threshold for the minimum score that a feature must get in the quality metric. A generic value that will help you independently of the number of instances is `0.0`. This means that all features scoring more than `0.0` will be kept, as they provide at least a bit of predictive information. You can raise that score upto `1.0` in the case of Information Gain; the higher the threshold, the less features you will keep. Additionally, a rule of thumb that has been used in the literature on text classification (see e.g. [Yang & Pedersen paper](http://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~ringger/Winter2007-CS601R-2/papers/yang97comparative.pdf)) is keeping around 1-10% of the features. In Information Retrieval, Salton stated that those terms with a Document Frequency of 1 to 10% of the number of documents were more discriminant (but Information Retrieval is about search, which is not supervised).

So, summarizing: you are doing it right -- keep on with attribute selection, but for simplicity, state 0.0 as the minimum threshold for Information Gain.